# Calculate transitivity for all networks in a list

Tags: r, igraph, transitivity

I have 500 random networks stored in a list

```
for (x in seq_len(500L)) {
+     gs[[x]] <- erdos.renyi.game(361, 695, type = "gnm")
```

I am able to calculate the transitivity for each network individually using

```
transitivity(gs[[1]])
```

How do I calculate the transitivity for all the networks and output the values into an excel sheet so as to do some statistical analysis. Anyt thoughts please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an *apply function, specifically sapply or lapply.

```
library(igraph)

gs <- list()
for (x in seq_len(500L)) {
  gs[[x]] <- erdos.renyi.game(361, 695, type = "gnm")
}

gs.trans <- sapply(gs, transitivity)
write.csv(gs.trans, file="Graph_transivity.txt")
```